# AngularJs if statement in ng-href and collpase ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I want to do a similar thing done here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible2&stacked=h with a small change using angular js.

Let's say I have a variable test, Now my href(Simple collapsible) will display only when the test has some string otherwise no href displayed.

I tried below condition in my angular template:
Simple collapsible

[[test]]

Note: I am actually having a condition like this https://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template-sharing.html but it doesn't include how to collapse ng-href.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more with sample ?

Comment: sure, I am having a Django template https://pastebin.com/8gUVDKKY which is using angular-js. I also have a variable 'details' coming from Js side.                                                Basically I am modifying my alert-message-template.                                                    Now what I want if details have some string(true) then an href Details is displayed and when i click on this href then I can see details string. if details is "" then no href is added.

Comment: Should I add more info?